# SQL Server Convert Varchar to Datetime SQL server

Tags: sql-server, datetime-format

I have this date format: 2011-Aug-28 18:01:00 (in varchar), and I want to convert it to datetime changing to this format '2011-08-28 18:01:00'. Can someone please help me in converting this in SQL Server?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Select try_convert(datetime,'2011-Aug-28 18:01:00')

Comment: I tried that but I get an error stating "Explicit conversion from data type ntext to datetime is not allowed"

Comment: nText is the issue.  You will have to convert it to varchar  Select try_convert(datetime,convert(varchar(max),YourTextCol))

Comment: It worked. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Happy to help  :)

Comment: And then you need to change your underlying table. The (n)text datatypes have been deprecated for almost 15 years now (since sql 2005) in favor of (n)varchar(max).

Comment: Just found out that one column has a different time format "21-AUG-2019 09-57-46" on which the above function does not work. I am getting the following error "The conversion of a varchar data type to a datetime data type resulted in an out-of-range value"  @JohnCappelletti

Comment: @saran the dashes in the time portion were causing the conversion to fail.  See answer posted

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Example**

```
Declare @YourTable Table ([YourTextCol] ntext)
Insert Into @YourTable Values 
 ('21-AUG-2019 09-57-46')
,('2011-Aug-28 18:01:00')

Select *
      ,NewValue = IsNull(try_convert(datetime,convert(varchar(max),[YourTextCol]))
                        ,try_convert(datetime,left(convert(varchar(max),[YourTextCol]),12)+replace(substring(convert(varchar(max),[YourTextCol]),12,8),'-',':')) 
                        )
 From  @YourTable
```

**Returns**

```
YourTextCol             NewValue
21-AUG-2019 09-57-46    2019-08-21 09:57:46.000
2011-Aug-28 18:01:00    2011-08-28 18:01:00.000
```

**Option with a CROSS APPLY and fewer conversions**

```
Select A.*
      ,NewValue = IsNull(try_convert(datetime,v)
                        ,try_convert(datetime,left(v,12)+replace(substring(v,12,8),'-',':')) 
                        )
 From  @YourTable A
 Cross Apply ( values (convert(varchar(max),[YourTextCol])) ) B(v)
```